# Make a button unclickable from another Activity using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, button, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I would like to make a button in ActivityA unclickable when I click on a button from ActivityB using sharedpreferences.

A code snippet would be great.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two separate things then:

1. In ActivityB detect the button click, and set or clear the SharedPreferences value
2. In ActivityA enable/disable the button depending on the SharedPreferences value

Step 1 (ActivityB):

Add this to the XML attributes of your Button:

```
android:onClick="enableButtonA"
```

Then in ActivityB create this method:

```
public void enableButtonA(View view)
    {
    //use the default preferences for this App
    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor=settings.edit();
    //set the enabled value to false, I would assume you'll want to change this to a toggle
    prefeditor.putBoolean("buttonA_enabled", false);
    prefEditor.commit();
    }
```

Step 2 (ActivityA):

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
    {
    super.onResume();

    //check the preferences value and enable or disable the button -- default is enabled
    boolean isEnabled=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("buttonA_enabled", true);

    Button button=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

    button.setEnabled();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put the `value` to the `SharedPreferences` when you click a button then in `onCreate` of your `ActivityA` you need to check if the value in SharedP`enter code here`references exist.

onClick button of activityB

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit().putString("button", "1").commit();

            //change actvity here

        }
    });
```

`oncreate()` of the activity A

```
if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(youractivity.this).getString("button","").lenght() == 0) 
{
   yourbutton.setEnabled(false);
};
```

Comment: In ActivityB i have this error : "clicked cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @MobiusApps put "1" instead of clicked. putString("button", "1")

Comment: I've tried that before and i have this error 
The method putString(String, String) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences